# Set priority for application pools in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have a website (ASP.NET MVC3) that runs on IIS 7. From this website, long running, calculation intensive jobs can be started on a WCF service that runs on the same machine, but on a different application pool.

I would like to ensure that the WCF service has a lower priority than the website, so the website stays nice an responsive. Does anyone know how to accomplish this? For example, is it possible to restrict the number of cores that are used by an application pool?

In my WCF service I already run the calculations inside a Thread with priority set to "Lowest", but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [this](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/cpu) can help. I think that you will find `limit` attribute helpful. Also, with `smpAffinitized` you can set affinity mask.

Comment: That looks very promising. I will check it out asap.